# Wifi not working with broadcom bcm43142 on hp envy, ubuntu 16.4

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, hp

My problem is that I can't connect to the internet on my HP envy laptop, with Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it in dualboot with windows 10. UEFI secure boot is disabled.

bcmwl-kernel-source is already installed.
The same for broadcom-sta-*.

I am an inexperienced user of Ubuntu. But, I can tell that Wifi worked for a while and then,  it doesn't anymore. I have looked for a solution on the internet but I couldn't find (or understand ?) how to solve my problem.

I have no internet connection from this computer.

The result of `$ lspci -nn | grep -i net` gives :

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev01)
```

The result of:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Then,

```
$ ifconfig -a
lo Link encap:Boucle locale
inet adr:127.0.0.1 Masque:255.0.0.0
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
Packets reçus:26316 erreurs:0 overruns:0 fram:0
TX packets:26316 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
Octets reçus:1954296 (1.9 MB) Octets transmis:1954296 (1.9 MB)
```

EDIT :

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
02:00.0 Unassigned class[ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTS22A PCI Express Card Reader [103c:80df]
```

EDIT :

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-29-generic
```

Tell me if you need more info about this. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Remi

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Also: `uname -r` We are guessing it is 4.15.0-29.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers making sure that the currently installed drivers are purged to avoid overlapping conflicts.

Comment: You are right, I think the problem is very similar but the bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.2 didn't work for me... I installed bdcom-0ubuntu4 instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl- 
    kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb`

This actually works for Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365]

> Caution: This firmware does not allow hotspot creation

Comment: Thank you for this answer !! This version worked for me !